# Can i rely over the "SSL on Shared Hosting"?

Tags: facebook, api, ssl, https, shared-hosting

My site will be using the APIs like Paypal and also making Facebook Apps. So lets say for Facebook, they allow only **https** for Apps to work with them. Mine is only hosted on **http** site.

- So can i solve this problem by buying a **Shared Hosting** with **SSL** included?

Is it a solution? or do i need to buy my own Certificate?

I'm not having enough knowledge about SSLs. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of providers, that offer an SSL certificate for your domain, on shared hosting. Normally they will handle the installation for you, not sure if you can install your own certificate. Some providers even offer to use their own certificate for free, you will have to use an URL like `https://www.providerdomain.com/yourdomain/...` though.

Apart from unserious offerings, you can distinguish between cheaper domain-validated SSL certificates and the more expensive extended-validation SSL certificates (EV). 
Both certificates are technically the same (the connection is encrypted), but domain-validated certificates are cheaper, because the seller only has to check the domain. The EV-certificates also require information about the owner of the domain, and the seller should check, if this information is correct (more administrative effort).

In most cases the domain-validated certificate is fine, the user will have no disadvantages and the EV-certificates are really (too) expensive.

Comment: You really filled my knowledge buddy, so much thanks. Actually, the first priority is to publish my FB Apps. I don't want to use the third-party SSL providers like, fbssl.co. So for this case, which way can be the cheapest one, among these valid ways you told? (Can i rely on the way "Shared Hosting with shared SSL enabled"?)

Comment: @4lvin - Supposed your domain is `example.com`, i would look for a provider that offers shared hosting with an SSL certificate for `https://www.example.com`. I myself pay about $50 yearly for the domain-validated certificate `https://www.fundzentrale.org`. It would be for free if i accepted `https://fundzentrale.hoststar.ch`, but i want the visitors to see, that they visit my domain. Delivering a page from `https://fundzentrale.hoststar.ch` would be safe, but it would be difficult to maintain a safe session between `https://fundzentrale.hoststar.ch` and `http://www.fundzentrale.org`.

Answer (score 0):

> So can i solve this problem by buying a Shared Hosting with SSL included?

SSL on shared hosting usually implies that you can not access your *own* domain via SSL, but have to use something like `https://youraccount.yourhostersserver.tld`

That means, other users on your server might probably use that same domain in their apps, if they only rely on the shared SSL certificate as well. Let one of them spam on Facebook, and in the worst case scenario the whole domain `yourhostersserver.tld` might get blocked by Facebook.

Also, if a user gets into “direct contact” with your app’s website, they might see this URL as well (as long as you stay inside Facebook, canvas/page tab app, most users will probably not notice it).

So I would not really recommend this option; at least not for something that you consider halfway important.